# Is the singlet state $\eta '$ stable under the strong nuclear force?

Tags: particle-physics, symmetry

According to group theory, the $SU(3)$ flavor symmetry for two quarks decomposes into an octet and a singlet. Is the prediction of this decomposition that the particles in the octet can only transform into each other under the strong nuclear force, while the singlet state  $\eta '$ does not feel the strong nuclear force ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two $SU(3)$ symmetries that are often discussed with regards to QCD. There is a gauge symmetry which corresponds to color charge which is mediated by the gluon and there is an approximate global flavor symmetry which acts on the flavors of the quarks (turns an up into down quark for example).

All stable hadrons are **color** singlets and thus don't interact strongly with neighbouring colored particles (as long as the particles don't come too close together). We only observe color singlets in Nature.

The consequence of the approximate flavor symmetry in QCD is that all the hadrons that transform under the same representation have approximately the same mass. This happens for example for the particles in the flavor octet. The singlet on the other hand, transforms separately from the octet and can have a very different mass.